# Rig Tank Track & Spinning for Game (Without Curve)

Tags: animation, rigging, game-engine, bones

I'm currently **rigging** the track like the picture below. Am I doing wrong?

I want the track spinning around whenever I move the Y AXIS of the Root bone.

Don't mind the tyre, I just want to know how the track can be spinning around.

How can I achieve that without using curve ? Because curve did not support to the other engine.

You can get the blend files here.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pf4f7OfceHMfI8K4XVgGKXM6Y4c2x6XD/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Thank You

Comment: Depends on what the other engine does support.  You might want to use rigid body physics if the other engine supports it.

Comment: I've never touch that features, is that for the suspension of the track?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found my own solution after the whole experiment, although its not perfect but its still looking good when looping.

I just snap the bone where the way of the track is spinning.
I'm adding 2 bones for each track. "track.001"..... & "track_conn.001".....  then add damped track constraint from "track.001" to "track.conn.001" therefore I can snap the tail of the bone to other track bone and repeat.

Basically, its just snapping from 001 bone to 002 bone and so on.

Pardon me for the bad explanation.

[image]